# Programming a Shell in C, Disappearing char** When Passed to Function

Tags: c, shell, pointers, malloc

I've only found a few threads like this, and none with information that I am able to make any sense of. I'm programming a shell in C and I feel like it should be easy but my C programming is not so fresh. I'm having issues with passing a double pointer and the contents disappearing

I feel I am on the right track, and it sounds like it has something to do with initialization, but I've tried a few things, setting pointers to NULL just to be sure. Thanks.

```
void runProgram (char **cLine);
char **parse(char *str);

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    char *cin = NULL;
    ssize_t buffer = 0;
    char **tempArgs = NULL;
    printf(">");

    while(1)
    {
        getline(&cin, &buffer, stdin);
        tempArgs = parse(cin);  //malloc, parse, and return
        printf("passing %s", tempArgs[0]);  //works just fine here, can see the string
        runProgram(tempArgs); //enter this function and array is lost
    }
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
char** parse( char* str )
{
    char *token = NULL;
    char tokens[256];
    char** args = malloc( 256 );    
    int i = 0;

    strcpy( tokens, str );

    args[i] = strtok( tokens, " " );

    while( args[i] )
    {

        i++;
        args[i] = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    args[i] = NULL;

    return args;
}
```

Visible in main up until this function call

```
void runProgram (char **cLine)
{
   //function that calls fork and execvp
}
```

Comment: You are returning a pointer to pointers to automatic storage, which goes out of scope. Using those pointers is undefined behavior.

Comment: POSIX [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) expects the second argument to be a `size_t *` and not a `ssize_t *`.  Also, it is mildly confusing to use the name `buffer` to record the buffer length, and `c` is normally a single character.  I'd probably use `char *buffer = 0; size_t buflen = 0;` and then `while (getline(&buffer, &buflen, stdin) != -1)` (since `getline()` returns `-1` rather than `EOF` on EOF or error — though there's seldom a practical difference).
As it stands, you don't detect EOF at all, which leads to problems.

Comment: @EOF could you elaborate?

Comment: @lloyd: `char tokens[256];` in `parse()` is an array with **automatic storage duration**. Using a pointer to it (as you do) after the function returns is not allowed.

Comment: What @EOF means is that you copy the string into the local variable `tokens` and then store pointers in that array into your dynamically allocated array of `char *`.  Since the input string is already allocated by `getline()`, you should just chop up the original line, or you should use `strdup()` to make a copy of it and chop that up — but then you have to worry about how the memory allocated by `strdup()` is going to be freed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest fix is not to use `tokens` at all in the `parse()` function:

```
int main(void) 
{
    char  *buffer = NULL;
    size_t buflen = 0;
    char **tempArgs = NULL;

    printf("> ");

    while (getline(&buffer, &buflen, stdin) != -1)
    {
        tempArgs = parse(buffer);
        printf("passing %s", tempArgs[0]);
        runProgram(tempArgs);
        printf("> ");
        free(tempArgs);  // Free the space allocated by parse()
    }
    free(buffer);        // Free the space allocated by getline()
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

char **parse(char *str)
{
    char **args = malloc(256); 
    if (args == 0)
        …handle error appropriately…   
    int i = 0;

    args[i] = strtok(str, " ");

    // Bounds checking omitted
    while (args[i])
        args[++i] = strtok(NULL, " ");

    return args;
}
```

Note that when the loop terminates, the array is already null terminated, so the extra assignment wasn't necessary (but it is better to be safe than sorry).